# How to remove “Proudly powered by WordPress” in Twenty Sixteen (2016) theme?

Tags: themes, footer, licensing

How to remove the:

```
  {site} / Proudly powered by WordPress
```

in bottom of generated pages using twentysixteen (2016) theme on version 4.5.2?

Would prefer if this change was not affected by later updates to the theme.

Note, that I could not make the previous answers work, for example through modification of `style.css` by addition of:

```
#site-generator {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: Not proud of WordPress anymore!? ... just kidding ;-). What did you try that didn't work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The quick and dirty way would be to either delete the two lines that are 'resposible' for the message, or wrap them by comments / comment-them-out. In your theme folder 'twentysixteen' look for the theme file 'footer.php'

Around line 50 look for the following two lines:

```
<span class="site-title"><a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" rel="home"><?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?></a></span>
<a href="<?php echo esc_url( __( 'https://wordpress.org/', 'twentysixteen' ) ); ?>"><?php printf( __( 'Proudly powered by %s', 'twentysixteen' ), 'WordPress' ); ?></a>
```

You can now either delete those two lines or wrap them with comment tags

1) html comment (will still be visible in the source code)

```
<!--
…
//-->
```

2) php comment

```
<?PHP /*
…
*/ ?>
```

3) css – Since the site info is wrapped by a div (class=site-info) you could also hide that section by adding this to your in your stylesheet style.css

```
.site-info { display: none; }
```

***The other actually more correct way to do it would be to use a [child theme](https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes) and remove the two lines from your child theme's footer.php***

If you don't want to go through the process of building a child theme yourself, here is a bare-bone child theme for Twenty Sixteen you just need to copy (and activate) into your themes directory: [Twenty Sixteen Child Theme](http://hyperlinkcode.com/blog/twenty-sixteen-child-theme/). You can then copy 'footer.php' into the child theme folder 'twentysixteen-child' and remove the two lines mentioned above.

Comment: Wow, pretty amazing that the WordPress team have made it so difficult to avoid the not-so-subtle advertisement.  Guess developers at Fortune and eBay have been through the same exercise, since I could not find any “Proudly powered by WordPress” in the bottom of their page ;-)

Comment: @EquipDev , it's not that difficult to find out that for anyone who knows a little bit of PHP

Comment: @bravokeyl: No, guess not, but I through the whole idea with a GUI based CMS like WordPress was that I could do my nice homepage without knowing PHP; so having the "Proudly powered by WordPress” is probably the fee that the not-PHP savvy have to pay...

Comment: @EquipDev , We only have to pay if we are going to use the default theme that ships with WordPress .. we can do a little attribution to WordPress if we are going to use it(it doesn't mean we need to) .. As we have a wonderful community who can help out the non-tech savvy and this question is answered a lot of times on `.org` support forums and  here also. :)

Comment: @EquipDev Note that with the first part of this answer, it will get reset if you update the theme. Use the child theme option if you want to keep your modifications

Answer (score 4):

The best solution to customize a theme is to [create a child theme](https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes). You can then copy the file footer.php from parent theme to child and edit it by removing the lines that outputs "{site} / Proudly powered by WordPress".

That way you will be sure that any changes made will remain even after updating the parent theme.